# Scopes, lambda and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, lambda, scope

having a play with scopes tonight in rails 3, and trying to get my head around what lambda does?

What I am trying to achieve in this example is get a list of country names (:name) from my countries model which is associated with my recipe model. A recipe belongs_to country and a country has many recipes.

I would like to order the recipes by amount of times they appear in a recipe, starting with the highest..

So i am trying this in my recipe model ( or should I do it within the country model?, but then that wouldn’t work would it as my country model is pre populated with 1 instance of every country in the world)

```
scope :top_countries, lambda { joins(:countries).merge(Country.name).order("name DESC") }
```

however i get this error message

```
undefined method `default_scoped?' for "Country":String
```

my controller

```
@toprankingcountry = Recipe.top_countries
```

obviously my understanding is not what i thought and would appreciate some pointers/assistance

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with **merge(Country.name)** part. **joins(:countries)** returns **ActiveRecord::Relation** instance. Its merge method expects one argument which is another instance of a ActievRecord::Relation, whereas you merge string Country.name.

Generally speaking, getting a list of top countries effectively means getting a list of Countries order by some additional condition. So I'd put this logic into a Country model.

```
class Country
  has_many :recipes

  def self.top_countries
    joins(:recipes).
      select('countries.*, count(*) AS recipes_count').
      group('countries.id').
      order('recipes_count DESC')
  end
end
```

Also if you are using RDBMS which cannot figure out dependent rows on its own (like PostgreSQL < 9.1) you'll have to manually list all the columns in group by clause.

> get a list of country names (:name) from my countries model which is associated with my recipe model (instance)

I believe it is impossible to achieve what you described as is because a country has_many recipes, not vice versa

Comment: thanks, apologies if this is an obvious question but what would the solution be?

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, I have however just tried scope :top_countries, lambda { joins(:country).order("name DESC") } and it gives all the countries that are being used but lists them 3 times for example (in order Z-A) if there are 3 recipes using that country...will try your method now though