# Rails 3 scope association error when using lambda

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, lambda, scope

So trying to write a `scope` in my `user` model and I just can't seem to get it to work.

My `user` model looks sorta like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user_profile

   scope :api_user, lambda { |member_code| joins(:users, user_profiles).where('user_profiles.member_code = ?', member_code)}
```

And my `user_profiles` model looks like this:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
```

When I call the `scope` in the rails console like so :

```
User.api_user(4321)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I'm new to scopes and I know how to do this without them, if I do this:

```
User.find_by_id(UserProfile.find_by_member_code(4321).user_id)
```

It returns exactly what I want. But I'm going to need to use this multiple times, (writing an `api`) so I would really like to get the `scope` working.

Have looked over these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245476/rails-3-associations-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827242/scopes-lambda-and-rails-3), but they didn't shed any light on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `joins` only needs to list the association, and not itself. So it should look like this:

```
scope :api_user, lambda { |member_code| joins(:user_profile).where('user_profiles.member_code = ?', member_code) }
```